# Using Systemd-Networkd for Multi-Interface Networking

Tags: networking, raspbian-buster, access-point, hostapd, systemd-networkd

I am attempting to create a multi-interface WiFi to (WiFi, AP / ethernet) setup. I am using Systemd-Network, and I am able to get the base configuration to work without issues. I run into problems when I try to add in the second `wlan` (in AP mode). The RPi is providing DHCP for `ap0` and `lan0` (future/not configured). Any devices that connect to the AP are unable to see the internet. I have checked the routing table, as well as iptables rules. Not sure what I am missing...  Any ideas?

**Please note that sensitive info has been removed from files and standard output!**

Current setup:

```
Raspberry Pi 3B+ (ap0, lan0)  
Realtek Wireless-N WiFi Adapter (wwan0)
```

```
                 +-- WLAN Router ---+
                 |  DHCP server     +-)))
(Internet)---WAN-+  192.168.2.1     |   *
                 +------------------+   *   
                                        *           [Rpi 3B+]
                                        *   +--------- SecureAP --------+
                                        (((-+--(wwan0) 192.168.2.129    |            
                                            |                           |               +----- Laptop ------+
                                            |     WLAN AP (ap0) --------+-))) **** (((--+     (client)      |
                                            |       192.168.219.1       |               |   192.168.219.50  |
                                            |                           |               +-------------------+
    +---------------------------------------+---- LAN (lan0)            |
    |                                       |       192.168.220.1       |
    |                                       +---------------------------+  
    |   +----- hexS SFP Router ----+
    |   |   192.168.220.50         |
    |   |           +--------------|
    |   |           |DHCP/FIREWALL |
    |   |           | 10.10.10.1/24|
    |   +---[_]----[_]-[_]-[_]-[_]-+
    |        |
    +--------+
```

These are the steps I have taken for my base setup:

- Download image from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/
- Using Win32ImageWriter, write image to SD card.
- Create empty file named SSH in the `boot/` directory.
- Insert the SD card into the Raspberry Pi, power-on, and log in. (`pi/raspberry`)
- Run `#sudo raspi-config`.
- System Options+ set Hostname "SecureAP", set Boot/AutoLogin (Console AutoLogin).
- Interface Options + set SSH (Enabled)
- Localization Options  + set Locale, Timezone, Keyboard, WLAN Country
- Reboot

```
Linux SecureAP 5.10.17-v7+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:29:51 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

- Deinstall classic networking:

```
    sudo -Es
    apt -y remove --purge --auto-remove dhcpcd5 fake-hwclock ifupdown isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common openresolv rsyslog raspberrypi-net-mods
    apt-mark hold dhcpcd5 fake-hwclock ifupdown isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common openresolv rsyslog raspberrypi-net-mods
    killall wpa_supplicant
    killall dhcpcd
    rm -r /etc/network /etc/dhcp
    rm /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link      (symlinked to /dev/null, prevents custom naming scheme)
```

- Create the following files / contents:

File: `/etc/systemd/network/99-default.link`

```
[Match]  
OriginalName=*  
  
[Link]  
NamePolicy=mac  
MACAddressPolicy=persistent
```

File: `/etc/systemd/network/04-lan0.lin`k

```
[Match]  
MACAddress=b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx  
  
[Link]
Name=lan0
```

File: `/etc/systemd/network/10-wwan0.lin`k

```
[Match]  
MACAddress=00:13:ef:xx:xx:xx

[Link]
Name=wwan0
```

File: `/etc/systemd/network/20-ap0.link`

```
[Match]
MACAddress=b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx

[Link]
Name=ap0
```

File: `/etc/systemd/network/10-wwan0.network`

```
[Match]  
Name=wwan0  
MACAddress=00:13:ef:xx:xx:xx  
  
[Network]  
LLMNR=no  
LinkLocalAddressing=no  
MulticastDNS=yes  
DHCP=ipv4
```

File: `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wwan0.conf`

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev  
update_config=1  
country=US  
  
network={  
ssid=""  
key_mgmt=NONE  
id_str="open_wifi"  
}  
  
network={  
ssid="Home_WiFi"  
#psk="`<REMOVED>`"  
psk=`<REMOVED>`  
id_str="home_wifi"  
}
```

- Enable systemd networking:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd
ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
systemctl enable systemd-resolved
systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd
reboot
```

- Configure WWAN (wifi):

```
sudo -Es
chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wwan0.conf
rfkill unblock wlan
systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wwan0
systemctl start wpa_supplicant@wwan0

networkctl status wwan0
ping -c2 8.8.8.8
```

- Update.

```
apt update  
apt dist-upgrade
```

- Switch to ssh.socket:

```
systemctl enable ssh.socket
systemctl start ssh.socket
systemctl disable ssh.service
systemctl stop ssh.service
reboot
```

- created /etc/sysctl.d/30-ipforward.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

- edited /etc/sysctl.conf ( uncommented the following )

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

- Create .network file for ap0

File: `/etc/systemd/network/20-ap0.network`

```
[Match]  
Name=ap0  
MACAddress=b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx  

[Network]  
Address=192.168.220.1/24  
DHCPServer=yes
```

- Trigger manual ap0 creation.

```
udevadm trigger --action=add /sys/class/net/ap0
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
networkctl status ap0
```

- Install hostapd

```
apt -y install hostapd
```

- Run the following commands:

```
systemctl unmask hostapd@.service
```

File: `/etc/systemd/system/hostapd@.service`

```
[Unit]  
Description=Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator  
Requires=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device  
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device  
Before=network.target  
Wants=network.target  
  
[Service]  
Type=simple  
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd-%I.conf  
  
[Install]  
Alias=multi-user.target.wants/hostapd@%i.service
```

File: `/etc/hostapd-ap0.conf`

```
interface=ap0  
country_code=US  
hw_mode=g  
  
ssid=SecureAP  
channel=6  
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0  
  
auth_algs=1  
wpa=2  
wpa_passphrase=`<REMOVED>`  
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK  
  
wmm_enabled=0
```

```
systemctl disable hostapd.service
systemctl stop hostapd.service
systemctl enable hostapd@ap0
systemctl start hostapd@ap0
networkctl status ap0
```

- Fix service startup

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@wwan0.service.d
```

File: `/etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@wwan0.service.d/override.conf`

```
[Unit]  
Wants=hostapd@ap0.service  
After=hostapd@ap0.service  
  
[Service]  
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 3
```

- Add rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wwan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i wwan0 -o ap0 -state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ap0 -o wwan0 -j ACCEPT
```

- NOTE: AP works, still not seeing the Internet when devices connect to it.
- Reboot (Issue persists after reboot)
- Diagnostic Info

```
root@SecureAP:/etc/sysctl.d # lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_state               16384  0
xt_conntrack           16384  1
nft_counter            16384  3
xt_MASQUERADE          16384  1
nft_compat             20480  2
nft_chain_nat          16384  4
nf_nat                 49152  2 xt_MASQUERADE,nft_chain_nat
nf_conntrack          139264  4 xt_state,xt_MASQUERADE,xt_conntrack,nf_nat
nf_defrag_ipv6         20480  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
nf_tables             196608  15 nft_compat,nft_chain_nat,nft_counter
nfnetlink              16384  2 nft_compat,nf_tables
cmac                   16384  1
bnep                   20480  2
hci_uart               40960  1
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             393216  24 hci_uart,bnep,btbcm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    40960  1 ecdh_generic
aes_arm_bs             24576  3
crypto_simd            16384  1 aes_arm_bs
cryptd                 24576  1 crypto_simd
ccm                    20480  9
rtl8192cu              86016  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        65536  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi               114688  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
brcmfmac              327680  0
mac80211              802816  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
brcmutil               20480  1 brcmfmac
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
sha256_generic         16384  0
cfg80211              761856  3 mac80211,rtlwifi,brcmfmac
rfkill                 32768  6 bluetooth,cfg80211
raspberrypi_hwmon      16384  0
snd_bcm2835            28672  2
snd_pcm               106496  1 snd_bcm2835
bcm2835_codec          36864  0
bcm2835_v4l2           40960  0
bcm2835_isp            32768  0
v4l2_mem2mem           36864  1 bcm2835_codec
bcm2835_mmal_vchiq     28672  3 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 bcm2835_v4l2
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
videobuf2_dma_contig    20480  2 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec
videobuf2_memops       16384  2 videobuf2_dma_contig,videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  4 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem
snd                    77824  7 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
vc_sm_cma              32768  2 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_mmal_vchiq
videobuf2_common       61440  5 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              249856  6 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,videobuf2_common,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
mc                     45056  6 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,videobuf2_common,videodev,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0
uio                    20480  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
fixed                  16384  0
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               32768  5 xt_state,ip_tables,nft_compat,xt_MASQUERADE,xt_conntrack
ipv6                  495616  32
```

```
root@SecureAP:/etc/sysctl.d # networkctl status wwan0
● 4: wwan0
       Link File: /etc/systemd/network/10-wwan0.link
    Network File: /etc/systemd/network/10-wwan0.network
            Type: wlan
           State: routable (configured)
            Path: platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.2:1.0
          Driver: rtl8192cu
          Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
           Model: RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
      HW Address: 00:13:ef:xx:xx:xx (Kingjon Digital Technology Co.,Ltd)
         Address: 192.168.2.128
         Gateway: 192.168.2.1 (Cisco-Linksys, LLC)
             DNS: 192.168.2.1
root@SecureAP:/etc/sysctl.d # networkctl status ap0
● 3: ap0
       Link File: /etc/systemd/network/20-ap0.link
    Network File: /etc/systemd/network/20-ap0.network
            Type: wlan
           State: routable (configured)
            Path: platform-3f300000.mmcnr
          Driver: brcmfmac
      HW Address: b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
         Address: 192.168.220.1
                  fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
root@SecureAP:/etc/sysctl.d # networkctl status lan0
● 2: lan0
       Link File: /etc/systemd/network/04-lan0.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: ether
           State: off (unmanaged)
            Path: platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.1:1.0
          Driver: smsc95xx
          Vendor: Standard Microsystems Corp.
           Model: SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
      HW Address: b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
```

```
root@SecureAP:/etc/sysctl.d # route -nv
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wwan0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wwan0
192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 wwan0
192.168.220.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ap0
```

```
root@SecureAP:/etc/sysctl.d # ip r
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wwan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.2.128 metric 1024
192.168.2.0/24 dev wwan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.128
192.168.2.1 dev wwan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.2.128 metric 1024
192.168.220.0/24 dev ap0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.220.1
```